# How to get records of belongsToMany relationship with pivot table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My Offer table has the following method

```
/**
 * Get the region for this offer.
 */
public function region()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Region');
}
 /**
 * Get the categories for this offer.
 */
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\OfferCategory');
}
```

My offer category has the following code

```
/**
 * Get the parentCategory.
 */
public function parentCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\OfferCategory');
}

/**
 * Get the offers for this category.
 */
public function offers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Offer');
}
```

How can I get records for Offers with the id of category and region?

Comment: can your please explain. eg. you want the Offer data of Cloth Category and region is INDIA ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$offers = OfferModel::with('region')->with('categories')->get();
```

This is the syntax of getting the relationship data. I hope it would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: This should give me all the records, I want to pinpoint the records which include the id of category and id of the region.

Comment: If you pinpoint the record using id then you can **join** the tables and put where conditions to get records

Answer (score 0):

Try this all offer where region(id) and category(id) exists.

```
$cat_id     = 1;
$region_id  = 1;
$offers = OfferModel::whereHas("region", function($query) use ($region_id){
    return $query->where("id", $region_id);
})
->whereHas("categories", function($query) use ($cat_id){
    return $query->where("id", $cat_id);
})
->get();
```

Comment: whereHas method for categories gives me the following error 
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `offers` where (`region_id` = 2 and `is_active` = 1) and exists (select * from `offer_categories` inner join `offer_offer_category` on `offer_categories`.`id` = `offer_offer_category`.`offer_category_id` where `offers`.`id` = `offer_offer_category`.`offer_id` and `id` = 5))

Comment: `$this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`[ref link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) use foreing key and local key in **OfferModel** then it will solved. id = 5 should be offer_offer_categories.id = 5

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with the following code

```
$offer = Offer::where($where)
            ->whereHas('categories', function($q) use($offerCategory) {
                $q->where('name', '=', $offerCategory->name);
            });
```